# Display table names of dataset in combox using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i have a `DataSet` which contains multiple `DataTable`, i want to fetch table names and display them in a combo box. Below code is running fine, but how i can convert this code in `LINQ`.

```
foreach (DataTable dt in objDataset.Tables)
  {
    cboTables.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
  }
```

here `objDataset` is `DataSet`, 'cboTables' is `ComboBox` of WPF

Comment: Honestly it would be near the same code with or without LINQ. You would not be saving any time.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
 cboTables.ItemsSource = objDataset.Tables.OfType<DataTable>().Select(dt => dt.TableName);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cboTables.Items.AddRange(objDataset.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Select(iter => iter.TableName));
```

Comment: Error 2 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: When you use IEnumerable.Cast, it converts ICollection to IEnumerable. So you wont ever have this issue. I think you are missing some references or using old .net framework.

Answer (score 1):

may be this works. Give a try.

```
objDataset.Tables.ToList<DataTable>().ForEach( dt => { cboTables.Items.Add(dt.TableName) });
```

Comment: Error 2 'System.Data.DataTableCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTableCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Path

Comment: try  ToList before for each

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `ForEach`, but I wouldn't recommend using it just to use LINQ as you have to convert your collection using `ToList`:

```
objDataset.Tables.ToList().ForEach(t => cboTables.Items.Add(t.TableName));
```

Comment: Error 2 'System.Data.DataTableCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTableCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:path..........

Comment: @user1523935 -- then you probably need to use .ToList() after .Tables -- don't have it in front of me or I could test for you.  Best regards.

Comment: Error 2 'System.Data.DataTableCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTableCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1523935 -- I'm looking right at it -- works fine.  Do you have using System.Linq; in your declarations?

Comment: yes,      Error 2 'System.Data.DataTableCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTableCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Why even use foreach just do a select and set it as the ComboBox's ItemsSource.

cboTables.ItemsSource = objDataSet.Tables.OfType().Select(dt => dt.TableName);

Comment: Error 2 'System.Data.DataTableCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTableCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:path...........

Comment: Have you added a using statement for System.Linq?

Comment: cboTables.ItemsSource = objDataSet.Tables.OfType<DataTable>().Select(dt => dt.TableName);